# Set based query to group data ordered data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of user action data and I would like to try and group it into 'sessions', so I could figure out how many times a user has logged on, how long they stay online, and how many actions they do during the time...

Full sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e24a50/4

Basically I have a table defined below, and I would like to group the actions when there is less than 20minutes of activity between two requests

```
CREATE TABLE WebsiteUsage (
      Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
      UserId INT NOT NULL,
      ApplicationId VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
      TimeStamp DATETIME NOT NULL
    )
```

Ideally, I would get a resultset that resembled this:

```
UserId      Session     StartTime               EndTime                 ActionCount
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
1           1           2015-04-15T10:28:03.887 2015-04-15T10:38:18.037 58
1           2           2015-04-15T14:40:26.277 2015-04-15T14:56:02.857 13
```

I've got the time between requests using the following query, but I cannot figure out how to group them based on when `MinutesSinceLastRequest` < 20

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *,
    PreviousTimestamp = LAG([Timestamp], 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, ApplicationId ORDER BY [Timestamp])
FROM dbo.WebsiteUsage
)
SELECT 
    *, 
    MinutesSinceLastRequest = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PreviousTimestamp, [Timestamp])
FROM cte
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a set based operation or do I have to fall back to the old cursor?

Comment: Where does the `Session` come from ? You have to include that as well.

Comment: Just a dummy value.  Could be a sequence or a random number.  Doesn't even have to exist on second thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by making a column like `CASE WHEN MinutesSinceLastRequest < 20 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsOver20`

Then wrap that in a rolling sum - this will change every time there's a 1 for IsOver20: `SUM(IsOver20) OVER (ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS GroupNum`

So now you can group by this easily. Include `PARTITION BY UserId` if you need to break it down by UserId too.